# Laravel + vue.js , data synchroization with db?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuex, laravel-blade

Lets imagine i am building an e-commerce website where user can put stuff in his cart. Imagine the scenario where user 1 put item1 in a cart , now the quantity is taken from the db using axios. Another user2 happened to take same item1 and commit a transaction while user1 didnt commit it yet(still in the cart).
Now the quantity of user1, item1 is not reflecting the correct quantity in the db using axios.

Any way to sync quantity in db with vue.js data quantity and update it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use sessions for cart state and then persist to the DB for checkouts. You wouldn't block users from simply adding the item, but if that was required you could hold the item for a given timeout blocking others or use a socket lib.

Comment: I could say you that the most convenient way to sync your DB with Vue is by using WebSockets and vuex. Both are a great combination and produce an excellent user experience. But in your case, you will have to fetch the whole products table and propagate it to any user viewing your shop, ending in a HUGE vuex state, therefore a lot of browser memory will be used just to keep your products state at the user's end. As @Tim said, the best approach here is just to let the user know that product is not available on the checkout page, as most e-commerce websites do.

Comment: Thank you Tim and Luciano for the answers. Regarding sessions I dont think is needed when vuex is present. I will check WebSockets and read about it. The other alternative is to set the state's quantity with some methods everytime a user commit to database, yes that will affect the quantity in every user cart, I still have to think how to do it, I am still beginner and learning regarding Vue.js :)